# I am unable to read text file using Java BufferedReader

Tags: java

I have been given a text file as:

```
Test: t1
mark1: 0
mark2: 10
mark3: 12
end

Test:t2
mark1: 0
mark2: 1
mark3: 2
end

Test:t3
mark1: 2
mark2: 3
mark3: 12
end
```

I am supposed to read this file using Java and perform some calculation on it, this file has 20 such records. I am new to Java and I tried using BufferedReader to read it. Here's my program:

```
// Java Program to illustrate reading from FileReader 
// using BufferedReader 
public class A1 {
    static int i = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // double backquote is to avoid compiler interpret words
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Assig\\datafile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String tot;
        String test[] = new String[20];
        String mark[] = new String[20];
        int avg[] = new int[20];
        int exsize = 0;
        System.out.print('\u000C');
        while ((tot = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (tot.contains("Test")) {
                test[i] = tot.substring(4);
            }
            if (tot.contains("ExecSize")) {
                exsize = (Integer.valueOf(mark[i] = tot.substring(10)));
                avg[i] = (exsize - 1) + avg[i - 1];
            }
            System.out.println(test[i] + "  " + avg[i]);
            // i++;
        }
    }
}
```

my program is going in loop not sure why, each line run

Comment: ..and what is your problem? your program runs OK and exits OK. It doesn't have infinite loop or any exception. Can you ask a specific question what you are looking for?

Comment: Its going in loop, the first value is read and printed 4 times, 2nd onwards values are read and printed 5 times, Iam not sure why this is happening, I only want each test to be read and printed only once

Comment: So, you don't want to print anything when **if** conditions are not met? move your `System.out.println()` inside the **if** blocks, and it will only print when your code gets into that block.

Comment: but now everything is going in the 0th position of the array. For the purpose of calculation I need to be able to total the mark1 for all the test and so on. Hence I need it to be read in the array. pls. suggest how to do it so that mark[0] should have mark1 of test1, mark[1] should have mark1 of test2 and so on